# How to parse a text file using regex

Tags: python, regex, bash

I'm trying to parse some log files to get some numbers out and into a CSV file. The log files have a lot of log messages but below is an excerpt of the lines that need to parse.

I'm trying to get the loss and accuracy numbers out of this text file below into a CSV. Any recommendations for bash or python tricks?

```
1500/1500 [==============================] - 1802s 1s/step - loss: 0.3430 - accuracy: 0.8753 - val_loss: 0.1110 - val_accuracy: 0.9670
Epoch 00002: saving model to /root/data-cache/data/tmp/models/ota-cfo-10k_20200527-001913_02_0.069291627_0.98.h5
1500/1500 [==============================] - 1679s 1s/step - loss: 0.0849 - accuracy: 0.9739 - val_loss: 0.0693 - val_accuracy: 0.9807
Epoch 00003: saving model to /root/data-cache/data/tmp/models/ota-cfo-10k_20200527-001913_03_0.055876694_0.98.h5
1500/1500 [==============================] - 1674s 1s/step - loss: 0.0742 - accuracy: 0.9791 - val_loss: 0.0559 - val_accuracy: 0.9845
Epoch 00004: saving model to /root/data-cache/data/tmp/models/ota-cfo-10k_20200527-001913_04_0.053867317_0.99.h5
1500/1500 [==============================] - 1671s 1s/step - loss: 0.0565 - accuracy: 0.9841 - val_loss: 0.0539 - val_accuracy: 0.9850
Epoch 00005: saving model to /root/data-cache/data/tmp/models/ota-cfo-10k_20200527-001913_05_0.053266536_0.99.h5
1500/1500 [==============================] - 1675s 1s/step - loss: 0.0409 - accuracy: 0.9881 - val_loss: 0.0533 - val_accuracy: 0.9855
```

Here is what I tried in python:

```
import re
text = r"""00 [==============================] - 1802s 1s/step - loss: 0.3430 - accuracy: 0.8753 - val_loss: 0.1110 - val_accuracy: 0.9670
Epoch 00002: saving model to /root/data-cache/data/tmp/models/ota-cfo-10k_20200527-001913_02_0.069291627_0.98.h5
1500/1500 [==============================] - 1679s 1s/step - loss: 0.0849 - accuracy: 0.9739 - val_loss: 0.0693 - val_accuracy: 0.9807
Epoch 00003: saving model to /root/data-cache/data/tmp/models/ota-cfo-10k_20200527-001913_03_0.055876694_0.98.h5
1500/1500 [==============================] - 1674s 1s/step - loss: 0.0742 - accuracy: 0.9791 - val_loss: 0.0559 - val_accuracy: 0.9845
Epoch 00004: saving model to /root/data-cache/data/tmp/models/ota-cfo-10k_20200527-001913_04_0.053867317_0.99.h5
1500/1500 [==============================] - 1671s 1s/step - loss: 0.0565 - accuracy: 0.9841 - val_loss: 0.0539 - val_accuracy: 0.9850
Epoch 00005: saving model to /root/data-cache/data/tmp/models/ota-cfo-10k_20200527-001913_05_0.053266536_0.99.h5"""
regular_exp = re.compile(r'^.*val_accuracy.*$', re.M)
for match in regular_exp.finditer(text)
   print(match)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, use named capturing groups:

```
(?m)^(?P<iteration>\d+(?:/\d+)?)\s+\[=+]\s+-\s+(?P<seconds>\d+)s\s+1s/step\s+-\s+loss:\s*(?P<loss>\d+\.\d+)\s+-\s+accuracy:\s*(?P<accuracy>\d+\.\d+)\s+-\s+val_loss:\s*(?P<val_loss>\d+\.\d+)\s*-\s*val_accuracy:\s*(?P<val_accuracy>\d+\.\d+)\r?\nEpoch\s+(?P<epoch_num>\d+):\s*saving model to\s*(?P<epoch_file>.*)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/TMLpTE/2).

Python code:

```
regular_exp = re.compile(r'^(?P<iteration>\d+(?:/\d+)?)\s+\[=+]\s+-\s+(?P<seconds>\d+)s\s+1s/step\s+-\s+loss:\s*(?P<loss>\d+\.\d+)\s+-\s+accuracy:\s*(?P<accuracy>\d+\.\d+)\s+-\s+val_loss:\s*(?P<val_loss>\d+\.\d+)\s*-\s*val_accuracy:\s*(?P<val_accuracy>\d+\.\d+)\r?\nEpoch\s+(?P<epoch_num>\d+):\s*saving model to\s*(?P<epoch_file>.*)', re.M)
with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
    results = [ match.groupdict() for match in re.finditer(file.read()) ]
```

See [Python proof online](https://tio.run/##rZRBj6MgGIbv/RWkl9F2VBBBabbT0x432XvtGqO0NatigE5mfn0XrJ04rdlMJiVR4PMR87yK3bs@ihafz1XTCamB5DPN3zRYAzmfzyEE2/V/2w54ACUwVACpQGnemXktlFoB6OMIQzPNi@Ik8@LdlpKYYFN6zevsSiGE4FAak4zGcPazE8URQNPCFVD5a9UeQCNKXgMtQCCF0EGZ69wr8uLI@2Ggmy7oERUIe2UvPAT/ZiEMISRh7EGIGMIZDDPoQ8pChmgYmzFL/COZIQJhYE9f8qYxm/KGScRuvFmM2Y23eTie8k5gPPLGj/bG1puQJKaURd/2jia94yi882bo1psQNukdkZF39GjvqPfGCY0x6t83@443mvQmlNx6J9G9N572JuPvnDzam1y8Q0oJpldvs7Vnkh9OdS4z/tbZ3c79QjRdVXNHPv1xNr9/VJrLXFeifUnLpbNZBaZzN26qlul2vdyZ3jOHJRUvRFsqy7nK1IaEBqL3T9XCknZssdS37AB8pDFA1/kd@JHmAF7nY3BhwMWnjEfwxMpyk7Z9@oMLt@OsPTW9jb355nUMy124vcnrxV@4T882wF@uCVWdaq1MoFvQ5Lo4@gcpTl1ZFdpxwV7ISxVULRjl7@@rtrR5O/bf64LdrJNVq51hNfd8/gc), output

```
[
    {'iteration': '00', 'seconds': '1802', 'loss': '0.3430', 'accuracy': '0.8753', 'val_loss': '0.1110', 'val_accuracy': '0.9670', 'epoch_num': '00002', 'epoch_file': '/root/data-cache/data/tmp/models/ota-cfo-10k_20200527-001913_02_0.069291627_0.98.h5'}, 
    {'iteration': '1500/1500', 'seconds': '1679', 'loss': '0.0849', 'accuracy': '0.9739', 'val_loss': '0.0693', 'val_accuracy': '0.9807', 'epoch_num': '00003', 'epoch_file': '/root/data-cache/data/tmp/models/ota-cfo-10k_20200527-001913_03_0.055876694_0.98.h5'}, 
    {'iteration': '1500/1500', 'seconds': '1674', 'loss': '0.0742', 'accuracy': '0.9791', 'val_loss': '0.0559', 'val_accuracy': '0.9845', 'epoch_num': '00004', 'epoch_file': '/root/data-cache/data/tmp/models/ota-cfo-10k_20200527-001913_04_0.053867317_0.99.h5'},
    {'iteration': '1500/1500', 'seconds': '1671', 'loss': '0.0565', 'accuracy': '0.9841', 'val_loss': '0.0539', 'val_accuracy': '0.9850', 'epoch_num': '00005', 'epoch_file': '/root/data-cache/data/tmp/models/ota-cfo-10k_20200527-001913_05_0.053266536_0.99.h5'}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting that stuff into `test.log`...

```
egrep -o  " loss: [0-9\.]* | accuracy: [0-9\.]* " test.log
 loss: 0.3430 
 accuracy: 0.8753 
 loss: 0.0849 
 accuracy: 0.9739 
 loss: 0.0742 
 accuracy: 0.9791 
 loss: 0.0565 
 accuracy: 0.9841 
 loss: 0.0409 
 accuracy: 0.9881
```

Answer (score 1):

To strip out the csv fields you asked for to the output -

```
$: sed -En '/ loss: [.0-9]+ - accuracy: [.0-9]+ /{ s/^.* loss: ([.0-9]+) - accuracy: ([.0-9]+) .*$/\1,\2/; p; }' the.log
0.3430,0.8753
0.0849,0.9739
0.0742,0.9791
0.0565,0.9841
0.0409,0.9881
```

Plenty of ways to improve the robustness and flexibility of this, but it works on the sample provided.

Answer (score 1):

with awk you can do something like this :

```
awk -F " " '{print $8,$11}' file.txt | awk 'NF>0{print $1","$2}' > newfile.txt
```

`NF > 0` : to remove blank lines

`> newfile.txt` : redirect the output to file

```
0.3430,0.8753
0.0849,0.9739
0.0742,0.9791
0.0565,0.9841
0.0409,0.9881
```